# I exchanged some BCC and LTC to my Monero GUI Wallet via Shapeshift, and my funds wont show

Tags: exchange, shapeshift

I am fairly new to the Crypto Currency world and have some experience trading and exchanging various AltCoins to one another using different services and apps without any hiccup.

Last night, I decided to try and get some Monero created a Wallet using the GUI Wallet. I found the receive address and used shapeshift to send a little bit of BCC from my Coinomi wallet. I generated a payment ID ont he GUI wallet but was a little confused when I tried to start the transaction on Shapeshift and it said the payment ID had to be 64 characters long. I deleted the Payment ID and tried to send the payment anyway to see what would happen, and it started! The transaction actually went through and heres the blockchain link:

https://xmrchain.net/tx/d697954fdec0b71784064927997ea392804c80713209d24ef3610c511550ff84

I waited 20 minutes and the funds did not show up, and I figured the reason why was because i did not enter the Payment ID. Before trying to troubleshoot and figure out where my BCC went, I did not want to lose on the opportunity to get some Monero so I went ahead and started another transaction on Shapeshift, but this time with LTC and using the Integrated Address that was generated when I clicked the Generate Payment ID button in the GUI Wallet (leaving the Payment ID field blank again on Shapeshift because the one on the GUI wallet was not the required 64 characters long). The transaction went through once again and you can see here:

https://xmrchain.net/tx/1a9e11d04711bd7b07ac872637472e1533ea060a2565e6ae9a99cd11ebc25e12

The funds for both transactions did not show up for an hour, so I decided to sleep and check back in the morning. Here I am in the afternoon (PST) and I definitely figured I did something wrong because I still have a 0.0000 balance in the Wallet. I noticed that the GUI wallet is constantly show Synchronizing, so I tried the cli version and managed to get that to fully synchornize, but even that showed a 0.00000 balance. I am a noob to Monero and treated it like the other AltCoins I have used, and now I am out some money trying to dabble in Monero. What can I do to track down where these exchanged coins went and possibbly recover them? I have tried to do some troubleshooting within the cli version of the wallet to find myself even more lost. I did not find a support email or contact on the getmonero.org website, and could not get into the Slack community, so I turned to here. Hopefully someone can guide me in the right direction to recover those coins via return to my Coinomi wallet or properly get the exchanged value xmr in my MoneroWallet.

If needed I can provide the links of the completed transactions on shapeshift.

My MoneroWallet address is: 496tk5NN3nPLtycwuYnDnEP4coURKSxuvMjPDtMiMEmfbzAnvqFqaFNWMg6VZGxHTXGze6TzZrgS7TsLsKggGqoo94hryLb

**TLDR:** I exchanged some coins on Shapeshift to my Monero Wallet without a Payment ID and the funds did not show up. What can I do to track where they went and how can I recover them?

Comment: Screengrabs of the GUI and Shapeshift transactions:
http://imgur.com/a/REDzr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of the transactions above have now been mined and confirmed. If your wallet is synced you are now be able to see your balance. If not [this answer](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/3273/how-can-i-use-monero-without-syncing-the-blockchain) will explain how you can validate receipt of Monero or you can use a block explorer and the [cryptography described here](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/4550/how-do-i-manually-decode-outputs)

Most of today there has been a large backlog in unconfirmed transactions because of a surge of network activity. This is a temporary problem which will self correct thanks to the Monero [dynamic blocksize limit](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-blocksize-limit)

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I didnt think it would take so long for the synchronization process but once it fully sync'd, my balance showed up :)